# Trying to write a query that will pull highest and lowest revenue and also print the account health?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

We are trying to write a query that shows us:

Programs with highest and lowest revenue and print their account health

This is what we have to start:

## Top

```
Select TOP 5 * From Health, Revenue
From Program_T, Account_T
Order by Revenue;
```

## Bottom

```
Select BOTTOM 5 * From Health, Revenue
From Program_T, Account_T
Order by Revenue;
```

Below are the tables:

Program_T Table:

```
(AccountName varchar(150) not null unique,
ProgramID int not null,
Revenue int,
Advocates int,
Shares int,
Conversions int,
Impressions int,
LaunchDate date,
CSMID int not null,
constraint Program_PK primary key (AccountName, CSMID),
constraint Program_FK1 foreign key (AccountName) references Account_T(AccountName),
constraint Program_FK2 foreign key (CSMID) references CSM_T(CSMID));
```

Account_T Table:

```
create table Account_T
(AccountName varchar(150) not null unique,
Health varchar(10) not null,
EcommercePlatform varchar(50),
CSMID int not null,
Industry varchar(50),
Amount int not null,
constraint Accounts_PK primary key (AccountName),
constraint Accounts_FK foreign key (CSMID) references CSM_T(CSMID));
```

Comment: Perhaps you just want `union all` between your queries?

Comment: I don't think I have used this syntax before. Would you mind explaining how it would apply?

Comment: SQL is just a language.  Which dbms?

Comment: MySQL is the database and am using work bench if that is what you are asking.

Comment: "I don't think I have used this syntax before".  Have you tried to open Google and search for sql union all???  Pretty sure there are tons of example.

Comment: yes I have. and it still is giving me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you found `union all`

```
select * from (
 select * from
 (Select  Health, Revenue 
From Program_T p join Account_T a on p.AccountName =a.AccountName 
Order by Revenue desc limit 5
 )a
 union all
 select * from 
(
Select  Health, Revenue  
From Program_T p join Account_T a on p.AccountName =a.AccountName 
Order by Revenue limit 5
)b) as w
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5 Health, Revenue From  From Program_T, Account_T Order by Revenue desc union al' at line 1

Comment: @Elizabeth i think you used mysql but you used sql server syntax

Comment: @Elizabeth does your dbms mysql?

Comment: Yeah I have to use mysql. What would be the correct syntax then? Sorry, I am a student and this is all new to me

Comment: @Elizabeth edited you have to use limit instead top

Comment: I changed my query in SQL to reflect "limit" and it is still saying: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From Program_T p join Account_T a on p.col=a.col Order by Revenue desc limit 5 u' at line 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189894/discussion-between-zaynul-abadin-tuhin-and-elizabeth).

Answer (score 1):

The clause to get the TOP rows in MySQL is `LIMIT`. You order ascending or descending to either get the top or the bottom rows. As you want both, this means two queries the results of which you'd glue with `UNION ALL`. And as each query has an `ORDER BY` clause, you need parentheses to show the DBMS what the `ORDER BY` clauses refer to. At last you want a final `ORDER BY` clause, because the result of a `UNION ALL` is not guaranteed to be ordered.

```
select revenue, health
from
(
  (
    select p.revenue, a.health
    from program_t p
    join account_t a using (accountname)
    order by p.revenue asc limit 5
  )
  union all
  (
    select p.revenue, a.health
    from program_t p
    join account_t a using (accountname)
    order by p.revenue desc limit 5
  )
) glued
order by revenue;
```

As of MySQL 8 you could also use `ROW_NUMBER` to rank your rows, which may or may not be faster:

```
select revenue, health
from
(
  select
    p.revenue, a.health,
    row_number() over (order by p.revenue asc) as rn1,
    row_number() over (order by p.revenue desc) as rn2
  from program_t p
  join account_t a using (accountname)
) numbered
where rn1 <= 5 or rn2 <= 5
order by revenue;
```

As to the joins, you can either use the `USING` clause as shown above or use `ON`:

```
from program_t p
join account_t a on a.accountname = p.accountname
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `UNION ALL` :

```
Select TOP (5) AT.Health, PT.Revenue
From Program_T PT INNER JOIN
     Account_T AT
     ON PT.AccountName = AT.AccountName 
Order by Revenue
LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
Select TOP (5) AT.Health, PT.Revenue
From Program_T PT INNER JOIN
     Account_T AT
     ON PT.AccountName = AT.AccountName
Order by Revenue DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. . . Order by Revenue UNION ALL Select TOP (5) Health, Revenue From Program_T I' at line 4.